# Ubuntu 13.10 64bit does not detect intel graphic card!

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, vgaswitcheroo

I have installed ubuntu 13.10 64bit on my laptop. The problem I have is high gpu temperature and I want to switch to my Intel graphic card but my system just detects Nvidia card.

Here is my CPU link info and VGA info
http://ark.intel.com/products/52231

How to detect my intel graphic card and how to disable nvidia card and switch to intel card?

Answer (score 0):

Launch "Software & Updates" and select "Additional Drivers". Wait few seconds until your system lists the list of available drivers. Check whether your Intel driver is listed. If it is listed, then you should be able to select it.

Comment: I've already checked  this way but there is no Intel driver. It just detected my Nvidia !!